# Why do certain function calls have periods before them in Rust?

Tags: rust

I am new to Rust and I am writing this example from doc.rust-lang.org(Chapter 2):

```rust
use std::io;

fn main() {
    println!("Guess the number!");

    println!("Please input your guess.");

    let mut guess = String::new();

    io::stdin()
        .read_line(&mut guess)
        .expect("Failed to read line");

    println!("You guessed: {}", guess);
}
```

I was wondering why `.read_line(&mut guess)` and `.expect("Failed to read line")` have periods before their callbacks.

Comment: Those are method calls, just like in Python/Ruby/Javascript/C#/Java....pretty much any language created since 1993.

Comment: So these functions control object inheritance... really? They really seem like rust's way of calling functions out of an object. Do programmers use OOP a lot in Rust?

Comment: Or is it a way to add code to a function that exists inside of an object?

Comment: It's not that they have periods in front of them, it's that the preceding call has a period *after* it. It seems that perhaps you were confused by them being on separate lines. Those statements are actually a single line of code: `io::stdin().read_line(&mut guess).expect("Failed to read line");`

Comment: "So these functions control object inheritance" um, no, nothing remotely like that. There's no inheritance at all. "[S]eem like rust's way of calling functions out of an object" yes...more or less. "Do programmers use OOP a lot in Rust" it depends on what your definition of OOP is. Rust doesn't have objects, so...kinda? However, quite a few of the types in the standard library have methods defined for them.

Comment: @JaredSmith Thank you for clarfying.

Comment: @Jared "Rust doesn't have objects" is a curious take. What Rust lacks are *classes* (or object "prototypes" that you may know from other languages).

Comment: @trentcl I don't want to get into the weeds of a semantic debate about what constitutes an 'object', so I probably shouldn't have said that. Rust has some stuff, and it does some stuff, and the stuff is good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`something.function()` is [the syntax for calling a method](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch05-03-method-syntax.html). The full statement is:

```
io::stdin().read_line(&mut guess).expect("Failed to read line");
```

What you see is simply splitting the statement into multiple lines for formatting. This is common when multiple method calls *chain* together.